# Datatable ajax failed with net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, ajax, laravel, reactjs, laravel-5.3

In my application that:

1- frontend react app served via node on (localhost:3000)

2- backend laravel server on (localhost:8000)

**ajax failed with error in console-network tab :**

```
GET https://localhost:8000/api/v1/testApis net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: try it over http

Comment: @madalinivascu it works fine, thanks

Comment: glad to have helped